# Object oriented page rendering

Tags: php, oop, templates

I am trying to apply an object oriented approach to my site.

I have the following objects:

1. error: Hadles all errors, kills application on fatal ones
2. database: handles database connection, queries etc
3. cookie: creates and reads cookies
4. session: sets and gets session variables, pretty much handles
   session
5. user: handles all my user information (is he connected? is his ip
   known? what is his id? etc)
6. page: knows all objects above, and based on the get variables
   decides what must be shown to the user

Generally, each object is passed the objects above it.

What I am trying to do, is have a page->render() function to render the whole page.

I have a headers array, a footers array, a meta tags array,and a scripts array, that the render function includes in their turn. The function looks something like this:

```
public function render(){
// to simplify im excluding meta tag and script arrays
    foreach($this->headers as $header){
        include $header;
        }

    //page sontents here

    foreach($this->footers as $footer){
        include $footer;
        }
```

My problem is how should I render database data so that they are rendered when the render function is called and not when I include the view?

For example, lets say I have the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SOME ENTRIES FROM DB");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc){
    include "views/show_the_entry.php";
    }
```

What could I do to render them when the page->render() function is called?

Am I thinking of the whole thing wrong? If so, can someone please provide a link or some information on the philosophy of such OO implementations?

Comment: You are looking for a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way I've seen to handle a view is to create the view as its own class.  So, you'd start with a generic view class, and instantiate it with the name of your template.

```
$view = new View('show_the_entry');
```

From there, you can set all the relevant data from your query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    $view->set('row', $row);
    echo $view->render();
}
```

There are a few advantages to this approach:

- Your views are discrete units that you can test. (Though, I suppose, you could "test" an include as well, it would just be a little more... cowboy.)
- The data that the view depends on must be explicitly passed into the view.  Using `include` means that the included view has access to all variables in the calling script.  Using a `View` class isolates the scope to only the things you've passed in.
- The `View` class, internally, can still simply include the file in `::render` (this is the most common implementation I've seen).  But you gain code isolation, reusability, and testability, by forcing your view to only use exactly what it needs, and explicitly pass that data to it.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, i do not know where you learned to use mysql with php, but that site was old. Really old. You shouldn't write any new code with the ancient `mysql_*` function. They are no longer maintained and PHP community has [begun](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) the process of deprecating them. Instead you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) pr [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) with prepared statements instead. The new APIs are actually object oriented, which would mean that your "database class" is a bit obsolete too.

For learning PDO you can [go here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) ..  as for MySQLi: i have no idea.

That said, i really doubt that you should be aiming for a full blown MVC-ish architecture for this case. And you should stay away from frameworks.

What you actually need there is to implement [a simple way for templating](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) and abolish the Java style *On-class-to-contain-them-all* .. or as you call it: `Page`.

Instead use a simple script .. something like this:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:...');

$user = new User( $connection );
if ( $user->hasLoggedOn() )
{
    $template = new Template('overview');
    $collection = new Entities( $connection );
    $template->bind( 'list', $collection->getSome() );
}
else
{
    $template = new Template('error-page');
}

echo $template->render();
```

And no, this cannot be called MVC or anything MVC-like, because *View* is not supposed to be a template, but an instance of class, which handles the presentation logic and juggles multiple templates. In case of Model2 MVC (also called - Web MVC) version of that architectural pattern, instances of *View* request information from *Domain Objects* in the Model layer.

But as I already mentioned, implementation of MVC in this case would be overkill. Also, before you even start to dive into MVC, you should learn what [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) is.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, looks like I will have to do some homework.

Answer (score 0):

The ubiquitous pattern that is widely used for this problems is the [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.
I think that is what you are looking for, but i'd suggest you use a framework where those problems have already been tackled. Symfony 2 , Yui and Zend are all good frameworks, which one you should use depends from the site you need to build

Comment: I am trying to implement the MVC pattern indeed, and I understand that using a framework would solve a lot of my problems, BUT the way I see it, in order to be ready to use a framework, you should be able to at least understand what it does and why. That being said, I'd rather solve problems like this before using something someone else built.